# $_REQUEST has data but nothing in $this->input->get

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

I am passing parameters to a code igniter function in the controller

```
$http.get('http://localhost/demoProject/index.php/fabricGrn/getFabPOPendingById', {
            params: {'fabIdArray': fabIdsArray}
           }).success(function(response2)
           {
             console.log("respnse 2", response2);
           });
```

In codeigniter function,

```
function getFabPOPendingById()
    {
        var_dump($_REQUEST); //data
        var_dump($_GET);//null
        var_dump($this->input->get());//null
    }
```

Why cant I access `params` object passed to the function via `$http.get`. What is the ideal way and other possible ways to do it ?

How is $_REQUEST different from $_GET?

As far as I know, `$_GET` is `$this->input>get()` in codeigniter. why does it not have the data passed through `$http` get call?

Comment: $_GET contains only get request params whereas $_REQUEST contains params from both $_POST and $_GET.

Comment: You are sending data in get, so it should be available in $this->input->get(). You can also use $this->input->get_post('some_data'); which can checks for both POST & GET.

Comment: Exactly and $this->input->get() has nothing here.I need to know what exactly is happening